# 軽い警告: Mixed line endings LF and CRLF とは、何でしょうか？

Tags: python

JetBrains Academy で、Python を学習中、
よく、

```
Mixed line endings LF and CRLF
```

という、エラーではないですが、警告が出ます。
意味が分る方、説明していただけませんか？

具体的には、

```
問題: copy the correct variables here

model_score = 0.9875
client_name = "Bob"  # 警告: Mixed line endings LF and CRLF
```

な感じであります。

Answer (score 1):

メッセージのとおり、改行コードにLF(0x0A)とCRLF(0x0D,0x0A)が混在している(ので統一した方が良い)ということでしょう。

だいたいOSによって普通に使われる改行コードが決まっています。また1つのファイル/プログラム内では統一するのが普通です。

どういう場面・ツールで出てくるのかは不明ですが、各ツールで設定出来るのでは？
[Configuring Line Separators - Help | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html)
[Configuring Line Separators - Help | PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html)

普通は使わない設定を敢えてするというQ&A記事
[How to Ensure Always LF not CRLF on Windows](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205969644-How-to-Ensure-Always-LF-not-CRLF-on-Windows)

---

JetBrains Academy というのはオンラインの学習プラットフォームのようなので、上記のような設定があるかどうか不明ですね。無ければどうすれば良いか運営元に聞いてみてください。

気になるなら入力やコピペする時などに、それぞれ元の改行コードが何だったかを意識してそれに合わせるというくらいでしょうか。

Comment: 詳細な説明ありがとうございます。多分、たまに、PyCharmで、コーディングして、それを貼り付ける時に、発生するのかもしれません。ですので、仰せの通り、PyCharm の設定が、CRLF だったので、LF に、変更しました。
これでうまくいくことを祈ります。

Comment: 問題があるページの、Comments欄によると、　
Hi, this is a technical issue with the automated checking tool, the Hyperskill team is already working on fixing it, for now you can just ignore it.　
とありました。
つまり、今、修正中であり、今のところは、無視してください、と、ありました。

Comment: 今のところの解決策としては、　問題文（# put your code here）の、先頭で、Enterキーを押すことにより、最後の行にすれば、多分その問題は起きない模様。　もし、間違っていたら、このコメントは削除します。